# R: how to setup log4j.properties on Java classpath for rJava processes

Tags: r, rjava

I am using a package (ravro) that in turn uses rJava to call out to the Avro Java library to do its work. That library uses log4j for logging and when I use one of the functions from ravro I get the missing log4j config messages:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I know that to get rid of these message I just need to create a minimum log4j.properties file and put it on the classpath. The question is how to do this in R? I did try to use `.jaddclassPath`, with the directory containing the `log4j.properties` file but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ravro in an analysis context, I have had luck with placing the `log4j.properties` in the work directory and adding that to the classPath with `rJava::.jinit(getwd())`.  You can check and make sure that the directory is added with `rJava::.jclassPath()`.

In a package development context, I copied [rJavaPackageExample](https://github.com/CeON/rJavaPackageExample/blob/75ec9679d0c1f8ddd67ac84d2cf16c0680f712f5/R/onLoad.R) and appended 
`rJava::.jaddClassPath(file.path(getwd(), "inst/java"))` at the end of `.onLoad`.